# Why when the object is reaching the target he stop and the move back and then make a ping pong nonstop?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Follow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform targetToFollow;
    public float lookAtRotationSpeed;
    public float moveSpeed;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 lTargetDir = targetToFollow.position - transform.position;
        lTargetDir.y = 0.0f;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, 
            Quaternion.LookRotation(lTargetDir), Time.time * lookAtRotationSpeed);

        var distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, targetToFollow.position);

        if(distance > 10f)
        {
            moveSpeed = moveSpeed + 0.01f;
        }

        if(distance < 3f)
        {
            moveSpeed = moveSpeed - 0.1f;
            if(distance <= 0.1f)
            {
                moveSpeed = 0;
            }
        }

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetToFollow.position, Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed);
    }
}
```

I need to make that if the transform has reached the same target position then stop and stay at that position. I'm settings the moveSpeed to 0 if the distance is less or equal to 0.1f but then he stop and then right away start moving back to the last transform position and make ping pong nonstop.

Comment: When I'm checking the distance I see that it's never get less then 0.5, I tried to disable on both the transform and target colliders but it didn't change much.  The transform get close to the target and about 0.5 distance from the target the transform like bounce a bit backward like ball bouncing. and then it's making ping pong. The target also have a Rigidbody and Use Gravity is checked true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you never prevent your movespeed from becoming negative. You should even go a step beyond that and make sure that it stays slightly positive. Use `Mathf.Max` to do that very easily:

```
void Update()
{
    Vector3 lTargetDir = targetToFollow.position - transform.position;
    lTargetDir.y = 0.0f;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, 
        Quaternion.LookRotation(lTargetDir), Time.time * lookAtRotationSpeed);

    var distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, targetToFollow.position);


    float minMoveSpeed = 0.05f;
 
    if(distance > 10f)
    {
        moveSpeed = moveSpeed + 0.01f;
    } 
    else if(distance < 3f)
    {
        moveSpeed = Mathf.Max(minMoveSpeed, moveSpeed - 0.1f);
    }

    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetToFollow.position, Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed);
}
```

Comment: I noticed that if I'm changing the value 0.1f to 1f at the line moveSpeed = Mathf.Max(minMoveSpeed, moveSpeed - 0.1f); then the transform will not slow down at all and will stop at once in distance 3 from the target. How can I set the slow down speed ? If I want it to slow down much slowly or not to slow down at all what and how should I change ? I wanted the transform to slow down much faster I mean if I set it 0.3f or 0.1f the transform hit the target almost not slowing down at all.

Comment: Sounds like you're just hitting the minimum. Try setting `minMoveSpeed` to be a smaller value, then.